# set a ftp repository with git

Tags: git, ftp

I want to change my repository from bazaar to git.
I installed Git (winXP) and tortoise with no problem, I set path variables, etc...

I have initialized my repository with:

```
$ git init
```

copied it using

```
$ cd ..
$ git clone --bare project.git
```

uploaded it to FTP, and when trying to access:

```
$ git clone  *ftp_address*
Initialized empty Git repository in D:/project/.git/
Password:
error: Access denied: 530 while accessing *ftp_address*/info/refs
fatal: HTTP request failed
```

I checked and .../project.git/info/refs does not exists. What am I missing?

PD: *ftp_address* = 'ftp://user%40example.org@ftp.example.org/git/project.git'

Comment: Are you sure your FTP access is working right? An access denied (530) error means you never managed to connect to the FTP, so there's no way git can do anything.

Comment: And a question to the other git people out there: when does git use info/refs? I don't think I've ever seen that path used...

Comment: I got my info/refs files using:
git --bare update-server-info

But the error continues.
I have tried using another user without '@' but the errors continues

Comment: typo error; if I use a user without '@' it works.
But that is a privileged user, any hint of how to use a user with '@'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing

Replace the @ symbol (or the '%40') with a '+' in the username

```
*ftp_address* = 'ftp://"user+example.org"@ftp.example.org/git/project.git'
```

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in [Git everyday](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/everyday.html), you need to make sure your `info/refs` and `objects/info/packs` are up-to-date.
Hence the  `git --bare update-server-info`

Regarding the `@` issue, the url is usually `ftp://login:pass@serveur`.
If you have an `@` in the login, that makes for an extra (and incorrect) separator.

`%40` should be the right way to include an `@` in the login name.

You can try as an ftp address:

```
*ftp_address* = 'ftp://"user%40example.org"@ftp.example.org/git/project.git'
```

(or some other kind of quotes or double quotes definition to better isolate the username)

Comment: I know google apps uses user+domain.com for user@domain.com where necessary. Worth trying too.